# Visualising 3D arrows from files

Tags: python

I have two files, one with the coordinates for magnetic spins(xyz), and the other file has the orientation of each spins( sx,sy,sz), and I  need to visualise magnetic spin texture with blender, can you help me with that?
here is what I want my texture to look like[image]

and here are snap shots from the positions file and the spins file [image]

[image]

Here are the positions:

3.535533764578643878e-01 -2.041241248209187953e-01 6.999999999999999556e-01
1.060660157657864255e+00 -2.041241248209187953e-01 6.999999999999999556e-01
1.767766938857864290e+00 -2.041241248209187953e-01 6.999999999999999556e-01
2.474873720057864546e+00 -2.041241248209187953e-01 6.999999999999999556e-01
3.181980501257864802e+00 -2.041241248209187953e-01 6.999999999999999556e-01
3.889087282457865058e+00 -2.041241248209187953e-01 6.999999999999999556e-01
4.596194063657864426e+00 -2.041241248209187953e-01 6.999999999999999556e-01
5.303300844857864682e+00 -2.041241248209187953e-01 6.999999999999999556e-01
6.010407626057864938e+00 -2.041241248209187953e-01 6.999999999999999556e-01
6.717514407257864306e+00 -2.041241248209187953e-01 6.999999999999999556e-01
7.424621188457864562e+00 -2.041241248209187953e-01 6.999999999999999556e-01
8.131727969657864818e+00 -2.041241248209187953e-01 6.999999999999999556e-01
8.838834750857865075e+00 -2.041241248209187953e-01 6.999999999999999556e-01
9.545941532057865331e+00 -2.041241248209187953e-01 6.999999999999999556e-01
1.025304831325786559e+01 -2.041241248209187953e-01 6.999999999999999556e-01
1.096015509445786407e+01 -2.041241248209187953e-01 6.999999999999999556e-01
1.166726187565786432e+01 -2.041241248209187953e-01 6.999999999999999556e-01
1.237436865685786280e+01 -2.041241248209187953e-01 6.999999999999999556e-01
1.308147543805786306e+01 -2.041241248209187953e-01 6.999999999999999556e-01
1.378858221925786331e+01 -2.041241248209187953e-01 6.999999999999999556e-01
1.449568900045786357e+01 -2.041241248209187953e-01 6.999999999999999556e-01
1.520279578165786383e+01 -2.041241248209187953e-01 6.999999999999999556e-01
1.590990256285786408e+01 -2.041241248209187953e-01 6.999999999999999556e-01
1.661700934405786256e+01 -2.041241248209187953e-01 6.999999999999999556e-01
1.732411612525786282e+01 -2.041241248209187953e-01 6.999999999999999556e-01
1.803122290645786308e+01 -2.041241248209187953e-01 6.999999999999999556e-01
1.873832968765786333e+01 -2.041241248209187953e-01 6.999999999999999556e-01
1.944543646885786359e+01 -2.041241248209187953e-01 6.999999999999999556e-01
2.015254325005786384e+01 -2.041241248209187953e-01 6.999999999999999556e-01
2.085965003125786410e+01 -2.041241248209187953e-01 6.999999999999999556e-01
2.156675681245786436e+01 -2.041241248209187953e-01 6.999999999999999556e-01
2.227386359365786461e+01 -2.041241248209187953e-01 6.999999999999999556e-01
2.298097037485786842e+01 -2.041241248209187953e-01 6.999999999999999556e-01
2.368807715605786512e+01 -2.041241248209187953e-01 6.999999999999999556e-01
2.439518393725786538e+01 -2.041241248209187953e-01 6.999999999999999556e-01
2.510229071845786564e+01 -2.041241248209187953e-01 6.999999999999999556e-01
2.580939749965786589e+01 -2.041241248209187953e-01 6.999999999999999556e-01
2.651650428085786615e+01 -2.041241248209187953e-01 6.999999999999999556e-01
2.722361106205786641e+01 -2.041241248209187953e-01 6.999999999999999556e-01
2.793071784325786666e+01 -2.041241248209187953e-01 6.999999999999999556e-01
2.863782462445786692e+01 -2.041241248209187953e-01 6.999999999999999556e-01
2.934493140565786717e+01 -2.041241248209187953e-01 6.999999999999999556e-01
3.005203818685786743e+01 -2.041241248209187953e-01 6.999999999999999556e-01
3.075914496805786769e+01 -2.041241248209187953e-01 6.999999999999999556e-01
3.146625174925786794e+01 -2.041241248209187953e-01 6.999999999999999556e-01
3.217335853045786820e+01 -2.041241248209187953e-01 6.999999999999999556e-01
3.288046531165787201e+01 -2.041241248209187953e-01 6.999999999999999556e-01
3.358757209285786871e+01 -2.041241248209187953e-01 6.999999999999999556e-01
3.429467887405787252e+01 -2.041241248209187953e-01 6.999999999999999556e-01
3.500178565525786922e+01 -2.041241248209187953e-01 6.999999999999999556e-01

and here are the corresponding spins:
4.673562022900126095e-02 3.956100436000106746e-02 -9.981235939180270744e-01
-1.079024463000091650e-03 -4.074460491400345996e-02 -9.991690111670847863e-01
3.890997631402084295e-02 4.913229802202631613e-02 -9.980340831025347192e-01
-7.859755671998435583e-03 -1.632854982999674964e-02 -9.998357878678008070e-01
2.640353565998995733e-02 7.488933282197150765e-02 -9.968422348266208211e-01
-4.715249633999512094e-03 -7.626205562999211103e-03 -9.999598028968965657e-01
3.211545405699919864e-02 8.633381573599785419e-02 -9.957484972979752103e-01
8.648854353000114473e-03 -8.769510372000115933e-03 -9.999241436260133398e-01
2.248341728600523545e-02 7.720578141001796513e-02 -9.967616381382320423e-01
-1.396783889999685352e-04 -6.864358590998452525e-03 -9.999764302577746067e-01
-2.338009740999788273e-03 7.931087693599281341e-02 -9.968471891469097290e-01
-2.848021969999691306e-03 8.711081479999055119e-04 -9.999955649608915920e-01
-7.817964500003731941e-05 8.979264542804286930e-02 -9.959604784904755315e-01
1.857709765799767099e-02 2.534424936999682670e-03 -9.998242186168747603e-01
3.500222615000327022e-03 8.284172321800772898e-02 -9.965565700630930612e-01
1.472885117199480322e-02 4.453776439998428753e-03 -9.998816054006471887e-01
-2.586287590401241746e-02 8.031357598603855452e-02 -9.964340626264783785e-01
6.121053180000275533e-03 9.063522535000409497e-03 -9.999401908450450405e-01
-3.540949740101222154e-02 9.420982340703251690e-02 -9.949224475643433374e-01
2.772848243999950085e-02 1.201781556999978332e-03 -9.996147692899820525e-01
-3.681271957401564127e-02 8.728253957803708274e-02 -9.955031802874230173e-01
2.176554511200896186e-02 -1.680616763800692193e-02 -9.996218353834116499e-01
-6.945788017002930970e-02 7.211242943403042838e-02 -9.949750752674199061e-01
2.377170499499934447e-02 -2.848846981799921588e-02 -9.993114194929724192e-01
-7.540406225398442464e-02 8.162941982898314075e-02 -9.938062513457948111e-01
5.775767328502387499e-02 -2.496536541801032058e-02 -9.980184275384126336e-01
-7.725459553700055049e-02 9.187860401400066435e-02 -9.927688802500072018e-01
5.498005530699355548e-02 -3.308271184299611811e-02 -9.979392404828829610e-01
-1.091494608800564758e-01 9.557379522804945737e-02 -9.894200548075120505e-01
5.895164201102420787e-02 -5.850956106202402640e-02 -9.965446980284092815e-01
-1.163144771679592987e-01 9.125203881496807279e-02 -9.890116317886539221e-01
8.381212920003833222e-02 -6.961621277403183539e-02 -9.940468348714545099e-01
-9.044889866597521921e-02 8.562835163497653501e-02 -9.922130729467281141e-01
7.755286609101802453e-02 -6.543282631801521088e-02 -9.948387297452311318e-01
-8.488377456797704945e-02 7.371854976098005108e-02 -9.936600627157312626e-01
6.119133592202388727e-02 -8.380557978703272182e-02 -9.946015509763883600e-01
-8.810867433396672721e-02 6.028232854597723178e-02 -9.942851212666243832e-01
6.289639179498221488e-02 -1.091443468759691199e-01 -9.920340495387193203e-01
-7.825068017300647327e-02 5.782778202800478023e-02 -9.952551324550822365e-01
7.252997425302462609e-02 -1.262758321660428784e-01 -9.893400917003358774e-01
-6.713446989500118645e-02 6.276879356300109347e-02 -9.957675639960174019e-01
7.190919154398058011e-02 -1.383839440019626332e-01 -9.877646238927333400e-01
-7.238565838501395677e-02 7.183205097701385322e-02 -9.947866469311918980e-01
6.691769138300367181e-02 -1.607018646180088384e-01 -9.847319093480541019e-01
-7.923106534503783493e-02 9.551826615804562270e-02 -9.922694690024738140e-01
8.573103091196541958e-02 -1.749414042589294283e-01 -9.808392811336043016e-01
-4.546484368698511247e-02 1.066341928329650746e-01 -9.932583233516747434e-01
8.323696752899467644e-02 -1.667099885779893542e-01 -9.824863291389371867e-01
-2.707111052300464893e-02 9.238727945401585540e-02 -9.953550851681709499e-01
6.460609509897767555e-02 -1.676957250319420223e-01 -9.837195719726599119e-01

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail? Like a mock-up of how you want the effect to look and probably some example data from your files?
Quite likely, you will have to use some Python scripting to import the data from the files and use it to create and/or modify some geometry. So you might want to do some research in this direction yourself as well

Comment: ...and a screenshot/image/painting with annotations would help a lot too...

Comment: that fits in fiverr more than stackexchange

Comment: It is unclear exactly what you are asking. If you need help loading the data via Python perhaps you could share snippets of each file. There are many questions about loading CSV data but perhaps none on loading from two files. It is also unclear what your artistic end goal will look like. How are you wanting to represent these two vectors in Blender?

Comment: I added a picture of how I want my figure to look like, and a snapshots of positions file and spins file too

Comment: @abualia: Thanks, it's much more answerable now. But: Why on earth did you put up a screenshot of text data? Whoever wants to help you now has to either create their own test data or manually transfer from your screenshot...

Comment: I will add the two files now, thanks for pointing out

Comment: I think those of us without a physics background are struggling to understand how your position and spin data relates to both the position and color of the resulting cones.  Can you expand on that a bit?